# I need to get the balance level of Qiwi wallet using the API [close]

Tags: php, json, api

I need to get the balance level of Qiwi wallet using the API, I got json / array output but I can not decrypt it
In output i get Array. I need get a euro balance on PhP

```
$arr  =  json_decode($res)->{'accounts'};

{"accounts":[{"alias":"qw_wallet_usd","fsAlias":"qb_wallet","bankAlias":"QIWI","title":"Qiwi Account","type":{"id":"WALLET","title":"Visa QIWI Wallet"},"hasBalance":true,"balance":{"amount":6.00,"currency":840},"currency":840,"defaultAccount":false},{"alias":"qw_wallet_eur","fsAlias":"qb_wallet","bankAlias":"QIWI","title":"Qiwi Account","type":{"id":"WALLET","title":"Visa QIWI Wallet"},"hasBalance":true,"balance":{"amount":34.48,"currency":978},"currency":978,"defaultAccount":true}]}
```

Comment: Number only (amount in the account)

Comment: Of course you get “Array”, if you try to output what $arr currently contains via echo or something - because it _is_ an array. You need to access a specific element of that, and then specific properties of that object … and so on.

Comment: `$arr[1]->balance->amount`. And if you don’t know which of those array elements is the one representing the EUR currency upfront - well then you need to loop over them, and check what the corresponding properties contain. (Either checking what the `alias` property ends with, or what the numeric `currency` code is.)